# @Document(collection = "Test") not working in MongoRepository - Spring data - mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to create generic mongo repository using generics of java.
I have defined repository as below.

```
public interface ICentroRepository<T extends Serializable, ID extends 
Serializable> extends MongoRepository<T, ID> {  
}
```

and I am defining document entity as below

```
@Document(collection = "mycollectionName")
public class SkuItem implements Serializable {

@Id
private String _id;

String title;
//Getter and Setter of _id and title
}
```

but it always picks collection name as serializable(a interface/class which extends T in ICentroRepository, NOT a value defined in collection of @Document.
Can anyone please help me in designing my generic mongo repository ?
Many Thank you in advance. :) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface ICentroRepository<T extends Serializable, ID extends 
Serializable> extends MongoRepository<T, ID> {  
}
```

to

```
public interface ICentroRepository extends MongoRepository<SkuItem, ID> {  
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks Shafs, but here the concept of declaration of generic mongo repository dies by specifying SkuItem in type. Due to which one will have to create all number of repositories instead of having just generic one.

Comment: What do you meant it dead, it is generic. You are making sure that you gonna have SkyItem only for this repository. And it is expected that every entity or document you define should have the type while defining repository..

Answer (score 0):

You shall create a `SkuItemRepository` which is generified on `SkuItem`, that's how Spring Data work, otherwise what shall it return if you call its `findById(id)` and ...?

And what is the benefit of creating a generic repository, when Spring's base repository interface is just generic. So you are just creating a marker interface which is not of any use.

Answer (score -1):

```
public interface ICentroRepository<T implements Serializable, ID implements 
Serializable> extends MongoRepository<T, ID> {  
}
```

I am not sure
Is that right?